# A safe regex alternative

Tags: regex, parsing

I'm creating a logging service that will accept a massive stream of log statements from various clients. I need to allow my customers to configure certain text simplifications such as:

- Replace any UUID separated by whitespaces or non-slash punctuation with a "*".
- Replace anything after a certain prefix with a "*".
- Replace all numbers between slashes with a "*".

The text simplifications will depend on the customer use case but I expect regexes to be a natural fit. However, since regexes suffer from the potential of catastrophic backtracking, one customer could ruin a server with a bad regex.

So I can't use regexes and I'm looking for some alternative with more tight complexity guarantees. It would be acceptable (and likely necessary) to put a higher burden on the expression author.

I've been Googling around but couldn't find anything that fits.

Comment: I've seen applications that just compile a simpler pattern language to regular expressions, e.g. `###.*` becomes `/[0-9]{3}\.\S*/`. But I'm not aware of any general purpose, out-of-the box solution for this.

Comment: You might want to check out the [RE2 library](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/WhyRE2), which is not a backtracking implementation and therefore guarantees linear performance. (To make that guarantee, it does not implement certain features, like backreference matching, which would require backtracking. But the limitations are not drastic.)

Comment: @rici Very interesting. I'll have to remember that one. I feel this comes closes to OP's requirements, although it doesn't appear to support replacements. OP would probably have to implement that part themselves.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ has a catastrophic backtrack warning and has also implemented a timeout so you could look into such things for your logging service.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/re2/re2.h#L401

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using regex on the backend while not exposing the regex engine to customers; customers get a predefined menu of replacement options that are implementing using regex.